# Unable to get HTML tags in RequestParam (MVC)

Tags: model-view-controller, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to send a get request through an MVC form but when I get the value in the controller using RequestParam somehow the HTML tags like `<li>` etc are getting filtered, any suggestion so as where these tags are getting filtered and any workarounds for them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using some URL Encoding like this `%3Cli%3E%3C%2Fli%3E` . If this is not working, you can try a hardcode encoding when sending and decoding when receiving. For example replace "<" with "|OPEN_BRACKET|" and ">" with "|CLOSE_BRACKET|" . Keep in mind, that this is a bad solution and use it as a last resort. Also make some checks for XSS attacks.